# It is possible to run LINQ queries over reflected generic collections?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm building SQL query engine that should take SQL Query as a string in the following format
`from (Collection) select (fields) where (conditions)`
and run it over my Data class (which consists of List fields like `List<Person>`) and return the result of query

I've already created classes etc. now I just need to run the queries.
Query consists of `Source` string, `ConditionsSet` object which have the list of conditions, and Fields string collection which consists of names of fields that we want to display if the record match the conditions.

Let's jump to the code.

```cs
public void RunQuery(Data data, Query query)
{
    var table = data.GetType().GetField(query.Source).GetValue(data); //Source object
    // var output = from entry in table where QueryEngine.IsMatching(entry, query.ConditionsSet) select entry;
    // Is something like this is possible? How to approach/do that? Am I forced to not use linq?
    // The compiler tells that I cant use Linq because it cant find GetEnumerator in the table object
}

private bool IsMatching(object entry, ConditionsSet set)
{
    foreach (Condition c in set.Conditions) // For example we assume the operator is == equality and every condition is separated by AND keyword
        if (entry.GetType().GetField(c.Field).GetValue(entry).ToString() != c.Value) //c.Value is string
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

How should I approach that? Is LINQ unavailable for me?

Comment: What is the type of `table`?

Comment: @NetMage it's unclear, it can be `Person`, `Order`, some Collection that belongs to the `Data` object passed in argument. I don't define it. The `query.Source` defines the type of table field.

Comment: `table` is a variable in your `RunQuery` method - it can only have a single C# type.